# iText 2D barcode not recognized by scanner

Tags: java, itext, barcode

I have a java Swing application which generates barcode labels to be printed on Soho stickers. The stickers are then put on actual items, in my case it is books.

I have followed steps for generating 2D barcodes as describe in the book "iText in Action, 2nd Edition" page 334. I generate the barcodes in a PDF document and print, but it is the scanning that does not work. My scanner is E-POS, model EC301 and can scan other barcode labels very quickly. My code is as shown below:

```
private PdfPCell createBarcode(String code) throws DocumentException,        IOException {
BarcodeEAN barcode = new BarcodeEAN();
barcode.setCodeType(Barcode.EAN13);
barcode.setCode(code);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(barcode.createImageWithBarcode(writer.getDirectContent(), BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.GRAY), true);
cell.setBorderWidth(0.1f);
cell.setPadding(10);
return cell;
}
```

To create a barcode, i call  the function like this:

```
createBarcode(String.format("%013d", 1));
```

Where could I possibly be wrong?

Comment: "This question has been asked before", you write. Yet your account is new and this is the first question you ask. Provide a link to the previous question. Also, Bruno Lowagie no longer works at iText Software, he is working on entirely different and wonderful projects now. Which also means that Bruno no longer has time to answer questions on Stack Overflow. Also, it is very rude to address just one person on Stack Overflow and demand that only this person answers your question. The previous editor did the right thing by removing that demand.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse thank you for taking note; i didn't know Bruno left the iText project. This is the link to the question i was referring to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43063277/barcode-generated-via-itext-is-not-being-scanned). Any one out there can share their thoughts or solution.

Comment: On that question, I asked to share the PDF. That never happened. Looks like the OP abandoned the question.